# Mapped Drive still appearing after remove and update GP on windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

My domain is windows 2012. And several common mapped drive and OU level mapped drive as well. I've already removed some common mapped drive and update the GP as well as checked by restarting my pc as well. still removed shares appearing on more than 300 users. Any idea how to remove unwanted drives ? Much appreciate your support.